# SH API access token

Tags: python

SO I have a code here written in python to generate an access token from the API using the secret key and consumer key provided by stubhub, when executing in command prompt I keep getting an error in line 35 saying

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users******\Desktop\Python*****.py", line 35, in 
access_token = token_respoonse['access_token']
KeyError: 'access_token'

any suggestions thanks

```
import requests
import base64
import json
import pprint
import pandas as pd


consumer_key = input('**********: ')
consumer_secret = input('**********: ')
stubhub_username = input('**********: ')
stubhub_password = input('**********: ')


combo = consumer_key + ':' + consumer_secret
basic_authorization_token = base64.b64encode(combo.encode('utf-8'))


headers = {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization':'Basic '+basic_authorization_token.decode('utf-8'),}
body = {
        'grant_type':'password',
        'username':stubhub_username,
        'password':stubhub_password,
        'scope':'PRODUCTION'}


url = 'https://api.stubhub.com/login'
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
token_respoonse = r.json()
access_token = token_respoonse['access_token']
user_GUID = r.headers['X-StubHub-User-GUID']

inventory_url = 'https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v3'

headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token
headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error `KeyError: 'access_token'`
Means there is no key with the given name `"access_token"`
So Before you try to get the keys, print the `r.json()` to display the json keys and see if `"access_token"` is there

**Example to print the keys**:

```py
import requests
import base64
import json
import pprint
import pandas as pd


consumer_key = input('**********: ')
consumer_secret = input('**********: ')
stubhub_username = input('**********: ')
stubhub_password = input('**********: ')


combo = consumer_key + ':' + consumer_secret
basic_authorization_token = base64.b64encode(combo.encode('utf-8'))


headers = {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization':'Basic '+basic_authorization_token.decode('utf-8'),}
body = {
        'grant_type':'password',
        'username':stubhub_username,
        'password':stubhub_password,
        'scope':'PRODUCTION'}


url = 'https://api.stubhub.com/login'
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
token_respoonse = r.json()

for key in token_response.keys():
    print(key)

access_token = token_respoonse['access_token']
user_GUID = r.headers['X-StubHub-User-GUID']

inventory_url = 'https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v3'

headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token
headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'application/json'
```